# PLSQL - how to extract month and year only from full date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date like 01/03/2016. i want to get back 03/2016 in date type.

I know extract function, but it give me char type.
I don't want to use to_char.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `extract` returns a number not a char. But you can't return `03/2016` as a `number` or a `date`. So your only option **is** `to_char()`

Comment: hey, the '/' its not important i jusy want to get back date type. thanks

Comment: 03/2016 is an invalid date...

Comment: date type must to be with days parameter?

Comment: A `date` data type **always** has a year, month, day, hour, minute, and second component.  Do you want a `date` that represents March 1, 2016 at midnight?  Or do you want a string '03/2016'?  Or do you want two integers 3 and 2016?

Comment: Yes. a `date` data type has been designed to store *dates*, not *strings*. In most systems, the `date` data type will, internally, store the count of the number of days since some important date in the past (e.g. 01/01/1970). Since it's just counting the number of days since then, there's no way to say "I don't want to store a day alongside month and year information". On the other hand, if you only want to store month and year data, you could adopt the same approach and store the number of months since some fixed month in the past, in an `int`.

Comment: hey ,thanks you all. i got the point.

Answer (score 4):

Date datatype always has a day, month, year, hour, minute and second part. 
You can use use to_char() function to extract the required component from a date.

```
select to_char(sysdate,'MM/YYYY') from dual;
```

However you can use below query but it will return 01-FEB-16

```
select to_date('01-2016','DD\YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: `TO_DATE( '01-2016', 'DD\YYYY' )` will output by the client interface using the date formatted (implicitly) by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. It is not guaranteed to return the date in the format you are suggesting.

Comment: Thats true MT0, checked it myself.                                                     select * from nls_session_parameters where lower(parameter)='nls_date_format';
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-DD-MM';
select to_date('01-2016','DD\YYYY') from dual;

Answer (score 2):

Date does not have a format - it is represented internally by a series of bytes which you can see using:

```
SELECT DUMP( SYSDATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs something like ( for the date `2016-02-17T09:13:44Z`):

```
Typ=13 Len=8: 224,7,2,17,9,13,44,0
```

If you want the year & month then you can do use `TRUNC( date_value, 'MM' )` or `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'MM/YYYY' )`:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) AS "Date",
       TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY' ) AS monthyear,
       DUMP( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) ) AS "Bytes"
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs (note, the last 4 bytes are all zero after truncation):

```
 Date                 | MonthYear | Bytes
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2016-02-01T00:00:00Z | 02/2016   | Typ-13 Len=8: 224,7,2,1,0,0,0,0
```

However, the output of the date is based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and your client will do an implicit `TO_CHAR` when it outputs the date using this format mask.

You can find out your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` with the query (as you can see above, mine is set to an ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"`):

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

You can then alter it using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/YYYY';
```

Then when you do:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, DUMP( SYSDATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

You will get the output:

```
 Date    | Bytes
-----------------------------------------------
 02/2016 | Typ=13 Len=8: 224,7,2,17,9,13,44,0
```

Note, the last 4 bytes are not all non-zero (the date has not been truncated) but now the output is just the month/year.

However, it is just simpler to **store** the date as a date (with the day and time components unchanged) and then use `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'MM/YYYY' )` whenever you want to **output** it as you will get the output format you want without changing the value across the entire session.